# Is there any way to initialize a global aggregate type inside of the main function? (Can't do it directly; have to read the data from a file)

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, constants, ifstream

I couldn't make the title very clear. That's because the scenario is very specific.

Let's say I have an object that will be used (get) pretty much everywhere in the code, so it's
preferably global. The object has const data, so it can only be set once. The catch: the data for
the object has to be read from a file, and I would like to have only one function to take care of
loading all of the data from the file into the program. So it takes care of that one
object, but also many different variables.

```
class IntHolder
{
  public:
    const int data;
    IntHolder(int _data) : data(_data){};
};

IntHolder importantGlobalInt;

void loadSaveFile() {
    // somehow initialize importantGlobalInt

    // load other stuff
}

void doSomethingWithImportantGlobalInt() {
    std::cout << importantGlobalInt.data;
}

int main() {
    loadSaveFile();
    doSomethingWithImportantGlobalInt();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to initialize this object after its declaration?

I know one workaround is to initialize the variable directly with its own function (like I do in the example
below), but preferably I want to do all the file opening and reading in one function, so that
it only needs to be opened once, and can then rest undisturbed.

```
IntHolder importantGlobalInt{loadIntFromSaveFile()};
```

I know the example of having an IntHolder class is a bit ridiculous, but I've simplified the
code. In reality, 'importantGlobalInt' will be of a much more complex type.

Comment: Plain assignment? As in `importantGlobalInt = IntHolder(data_read_from_file);`?

Comment: @INEEDANSWERS: Are you saying the reason you don't want to use in-place initialization (like 'Some programmer dude' alluded to) is that you need to do other things with the file as well and don't want to have to open and close it multiple times?

Comment: All global objects are initialized before `main` is entered. You can try to write your global object such that its initialization will read the file like you wrote, but all this has to happen before `main`.

Comment: ***If*** you write some code that will be invoked before `main` (which is possible) then you also have to think about [the static initialization order fiasco](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.htm).

Comment: @scg Well... that, and the fact that I would like to keep everything that has to do with reading from the file in one place, in one function.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see... Oh yeah, I forgot about that (about reading from the file inside of the constructor). Although it still means that I can't do all the file reading in one place. But it seems like that's impossible anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OoOOoh, that does sound like an interesting article. Thanks :)  However, the link you provided doesn't work. Could you update it?

Comment: I don't know for sure what 'Some programmer dude' was linking to, but [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) is a commonly referenced article on the subject. There are ways around it, but it might be worth reconsidering whether your objects need to be global. It can be convenient of course, but there are other options, such as creating them locally and passing them forward to whoever needs them.

Comment: @scg Alright, so let's say I don't make the objects global and define them in main. What if it's a very long list of objects? Like dozens of them, who all need to be used in the next functions and underlying functions of those. Would I really need to keep writing parameters to keep passing them? There must be another way, right?

Comment: Yes, it could mean passing many things forward and having many function parameters. Depending on what types of objects they are, you could ameliorate the issue by grouping objects together into containers if certain groups of objects are always used together. You could have e.g. an `AllMyObjects` class that aggregates all the other objects, and just pass forward an instance of that. I suspect though that the real question is what these dozes of objects are, as there might be a more appropriate solution for your particular situation.

Comment: @scg Ah okay. Thank you for the answer. Fortunately, I can inform you: the situation was purely hypothetical. I was thinking of some sort of videogame setting, where all of the save file data was loaded into game. The reason I didn't want to have to reopen and close a file the whole time was because I presumed that doing that would be terribly inefficient, costing a lot of performance. But could I take from your earlier comment that that's not the case?

Comment: Game applications load stuff at arbitrary times as a matter of course, so I wouldn't worry about that. In fact, I think it'd probably be highly unusual for a game to load everything before main() or an equivalent entry point. If you're worried about load times, you could time it in a typical environment and see if it seems like an issue. Another common solution is to perform loading on a secondary thread. In any case, I suspect having many global objects or loading everything before main() executes is neither necessary nor optimal, so I'd recommend pursuing other strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Would a lazily intitialized singleton suffice?

Some nice examples for workarounds wrt. the static init order fiasco
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use

The downside is that youre still doing an assignment when getting the instance and not just declaring it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class IntHolder
{
protected:
  static std::shared_ptr<IntHolder> loadSaveFile();

public:
  IntHolder(int _data) : data(_data){};    
  // singleton
  static IntHolder& GetInstance(); 

public: // data
  const int data;
};

// Do all your initialization
std::shared_ptr<IntHolder> IntHolder::loadSaveFile()
{
  static int _data = 42;
  return std::make_unique<IntHolder>(_data++);
}

// lazyily initialized singleton
IntHolder& IntHolder::GetInstance()
{
  static std::shared_ptr<IntHolder> m_instance;
  if(!m_instance)
  {
    m_instance = IntHolder::loadSaveFile();
  }
  return *m_instance;
};

// Get instance
IntHolder& importantGlobalInt = IntHolder::GetInstance();
IntHolder& importantGlobalInt2 = IntHolder::GetInstance();

void doSomethingWithImportantGlobalInt() {
   std::cout << importantGlobalInt.data;
   std::cout << "\n"<< importantGlobalInt2.data;
}

int main() {
  //loadSaveFile();
  doSomethingWithImportantGlobalInt();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah that's actually pretty good. I didn't know about singletons and your answer has made me learn about them. I can work with this. It's not a perfect solution to the semi-hypothetical situation I set up, but other comments have taught me my strategy wasn't optimal in the first place. I'm sure I can find something with all the answers including yours. Thanks a lot!